# Can someone please explain how I can get my images have an higher height in the container that they are in and not be cropped. (Tailwind CSS)

Tags: css, image, grid, tailwind-css

I'm currently creating a portfolio website using tailwind, react, typescript and framer-motion. I have section inside of the site for displaying my projects in a form of card. The cards are contained inside of a grid. The cards contain a image and then a div that is positioned absolute that appears when the user hover over the card. The issue is that I need to make my cards bigger so that image can be easily seen on medium sized screens and that the text from the absolute div can be read without it overflowing it's container. If I try to make the image bigger then the image gets cropped and I want to avoid that. So I'm looking for a way to make it so my image keeps it's aspect ratio and can be bigger (To a static height) without it having to be cropped. Please see the code below:

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

import { SiGithub, SiReact, SiTailwindcss } from 'react-icons/si';
import spotifyStats from '../assets/Spotify-Stats.png';
import flasher from '../assets/Flasher.png';

export default function Projects() {
  const fadeUp = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 20,
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
    },
  };

  const fadeIn = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        when: 'beforeChildren',
        staggerChildren: 0.45,
      },
    },
  };

  const scaleIn = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0,
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.4,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <section className='my-40'>
      <motion.h2
        variants={fadeUp}
        initial={'hidden'}
        whileInView={'visible'}
        viewport={{ once: false, amount: 0.5 }}
        className='text-center text-4xl'
      >
        Projects
      </motion.h2>

      <motion.div
        variants={fadeIn}
        initial={'hidden'}
        whileInView={'visible'}
        viewport={{ once: false, amount: 0.1 }}
        className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 mt-6'
      >
        <motion.div
          variants={scaleIn}
          className='w-full group hover:cursor-pointer'
        >
          <div className='relative overflow-hidden rounded-xl'>
            <img
              className='w-full object-cover group-hover:scale-125 group-hover:rotate-3 duration-500'
              src={spotifyStats}
              alt='Photo'
            />
            <div className='absolute h-full w-full bg-black/90 flex flex-col gap-2 items-center text-center justify-center -bottom-96 group-hover:bottom-0 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all duration-300 text-xs'>
              <h2>Spotify Stats Web App</h2>
              <p>Tech Stack:</p>
              <ul className='list-none flex gap-2'>
                <li>
                  <SiReact size={20} />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <SiTailwindcss size={20} />
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p>Git Repo:</p>
              <a
                href='#'
                target='_blank'
              >
                <SiGithub size={20} />
              </a>
              <p>Link to Live Site:</p>
              <></>
              <small>
                Description: A web app using Spotify's api to show the user
                their most listened to music artist and tracks in a specific
                time frame. (Similarly to Spotify rewind that comes out every
                year)
              </small>
              <small>
                Please note: This site will not allow spotify accounts to work
                unless they are added to the developers list (Please contact me
                in the form below if you would like to be added)
              </small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </motion.div>
        {/* <motion.div
          variants={scaleIn}
          className='w-full group hover:cursor-pointer '
        >
          <div className='relative overflow-hidden rounded-xl'>
            <img
              className='w-full object-cover group-hover:scale-125 group-hover:rotate-3 duration-500'
              src={flasher}
              alt='A social media meets flash card sharing experience'
            />

            <div className='absolute h-full w-full bg-black/90 flex flex-col items-center justify-center -bottom-96 group-hover:bottom-0 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all duration-300'>
              <h2>Flasher</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </motion.div> */}
      </motion.div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I have attempted to modify the height of both the motion div and relative div this doesn't change the height of the image at all. If I use object-fill the image get stretched and is unable to be viewed properly on mobile. If I use object-cover then the image is cropped. I'm trying to avoid these. I want the image to be roughly 500px in height and stay the same aspect ratio with the width being the full grid column.

Please help I really suck with images and I've been trying to fix this for the past hour and half with no avail!

Comment: maybe make a codesandbox or a stackblitz? it helps to reproduce your issue

Comment: If you are going to ask a html or css question, you need to show the generated html and css and not whatever code that is you are showing. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your image in a container and set a fixed height for that container. For instance, you can use h-96 in Tailwind to set the height to 384px (feel free to adjust this to your liking).

Then, for your image, use object-contain and h-full. This will make your image fill its container while keeping its original aspect ratio, avoiding any distortion or cropping.

Here's a snippet of how your code could look:

```
<div className='relative overflow-hidden rounded-xl h-96'>
  <img
    className='w-full h-full object-contain group-hover:scale-125 group-hover:rotate-3 duration-500'
    src={spotifyStats}
    alt='Photo'
  />
  ////Rest of the code 
</div>
```